# How can I determine which elements in a list are integers and which are strings?

Tags: python, string, list

In Python 3.6, I need to determine which elements from a list contain integers, floats, or strings.

When I use "type" function it returns it's a list element, but what is contained inside that element? a string or a function?

```
my_list=[3],['XX'],[0],[1],[4],['3']
type(my_list[0])
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: You know how to look *inside* lists, right? `type(my_list[0][0])`. (`my_list`, by the way, is a `tuple`, not a `list`.)

Answer (score 3):

You got `list` because you checked the element at index `0` in the `tuple`, which is a `list`

```
>>> my_list=[3],['XX'],[0],[1],[4],['3'] # my_list is a tuple now :)
>>> [y.__class__ for x in my_list for y in x]
[<type 'int'>, <type 'str'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'str'>]
>>> [y.__class__.__name__ for x in my_list for y in x]
['int', 'str', 'int', 'int', 'int', 'str']
```

Comment: Thanks! nice solution!

Comment: One shouldn't directly use `dunder` attributes usually : ). Use `type` instead :)

Answer (score 1):

`type` returns list because what you have is a tuple of lists

```
my_list=[3],['XX'],[0],[1],[4],['3']
```

is equivalent to

```
my_list=([3],['XX'],[0],[1],[4],['3'])
```

you want to define it as

```
my_list = [3,'xx',0,1,4,'3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `my_list` variable is a lists of lists. Try again with

```
my_list=[3,'XX', 0, 1, 4, '3']
```